# Is there a way to print coloured text in python if I'm not using the built-in print function?

Tags: python, text, colors, output

I'm making a text based game and ideally I would like to have text in a different colour in specific sections

I've figured out how to change the colour of text using the basic built-in print function, like this:

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
colorama.init()

print('\033[31m' + 'red text here')
print('\033[39m')
input("\n[Press enter to continue]")
```

In my game I make most of the text appear letter by letter with this code:

```
import time 
import sys 
import keyboard 

def print_ci(s):    
    for c in s:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl"):
            sys.stdout.write(c)
            sys.stdout.flush()
        else:
            sys.stdout.write(c)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.035)

print_ci ("sample text that appears letter by letter")
```

I want to make the text that appears letter by letter to be in a certain colour at specific points of the program.

I've tried this:

```
import time 
import sys 
import keyboard
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
colorama.init()

def print_ci(s):    
    for c in s:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl"):
            sys.stdout.write(c)
            sys.stdout.flush()
        else:
            sys.stdout.write(c)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.035)

print_ci ("\033[31m" + "sample text that appears letter by letter")
print_ci ('\033[39m')
```

But I just get this output:

```
[31msample text that appears letter by letter[39m
```

I've also tried this colour changing method:

```
import time 
import sys 
import keyboard
from colorama import init
from termcolor import colored

init()

def print_ci(s):   
    for c in s:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl"):
            sys.stdout.write(c)
            sys.stdout.flush()
        else:
            sys.stdout.write(c)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.035)

print_ci(colored('Hello, World!', 'green',))
```

But I still got the same output.
Any ways to fixt this?

Comment: If you are talking about printing text with different colours in **python shell** , I am sorry , but I think there is no way , but if you run the code you have written above in **command line** , you will see colored text .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a method thanks to u/socal_nerdtastic on Reddit

Firstly I changed the sys.stdout code to this

```
import time  
import keyboard   

def print_ci(s): 
    for c in s:        
         print(c, end='', flush=True)
         if not keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl"):
             time.sleep(0.035)  

print_ci ("sample text that appears letter by letter")
```

then I edited it to this

```
import time  
import keyboard   
import colorama 
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style 
colorama.init()  

def print_ci(s, color=''): 
    print(color) # set the text color
    for c in s:        
         print(c, end='', flush=True)
         if not keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl"):
             time.sleep(0.035)  
    print('\033[39m') # reset the terminal color

print_ci("sample text that appears in red", color='\033[31m')
print_ci("normal text")
```

it doesn't actually go back to the normal text for me but if you make different print function you can use them to make text of multiple different colors

Here's the link to the thread on reddit if you need it:
https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/lc7e8o/is_there_a_way_to_print_coloured_text_in_python/